# error: ‘scmp_filter_ctx’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: sandbox, seccomp

I am getting compilation error:`error: ‘scmp_filter_ctx’ was not declared in this scope`.
I have declared a seccomp filter.
`scmp_filter_ctx ctx;`

I have included the library `#include <linux/seccomp.h>`
and already installed the library `libseccomp-dev` using 
`sudo apt-get install libseccomp-dev`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <linux/seccomp.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void create_sandbox(){
scmp_filter_ctx ctx;
ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_KILL); // default action: kill

seccomp_load(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this error using the following:

Replaced `#include <linux/seccomp.h>` with `#include <seccomp.h>`
and while compiling, used `g++ filename.cpp -lseccomp`.

This worked for me.